# Configuring apache virtualhost for running webmin with SSL, but without certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost, webmin

I am developing a web portal for my home server.
I am running a FreeBSD 10.3 server and have apache24 installed.

What I'd like to achieve is running the webmin https://localhost:10000/ port to a subdomain under my app: https://webmin.somedomain.com

I have multiple apps that I have connected using the following httpd.conf virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@gmail.com
    ServerName webmin.somedomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / "http://localhost:10000/"
    ProxyPassReverse / "http://localhost:10000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine for a non-SSL page. But because webmin can do a lot of harm, I prefer it to run under SSL.

To get the configuration working, I changed the lines to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@gmail.com
    ServerName webmin.somedomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / "https://localhost:10000/"
    ProxyPassReverse / "https://localhost:10000/"
</VirtualHost>
```

However, this does not work.

It worked on SSL before, but probably only because I ran webmin on https://{device IP}:10000/ and not on any vhost or via apache.

I don't get any response from the server on the https://webmin.somedomain.com URL, so I think I am missing something..

**Questions**
1. Do I need to configure mod_ssl on apache to get this running?
2. Is a certificate and certificate configuration REQUIRED to run a uncertificated connection with my server?
3. Where to start from here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you need to enable `SSLProxyEngine` by setting it to `on`.

By looking at the logs you can find the following on *Apache 2.4*.

```
SSL Proxy requested for webmin.yourdomain.com:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
```

> **[SSLProxyEngine Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLProxyEngine)**
>
> This directive toggles the usage of the SSL/TLS Protocol Engine for proxy. This is usually used inside a  section to enable SSL/TLS for proxy usage in a particular virtual host. By default the SSL/TLS Protocol Engine is disabled for proxy both for the main server and all configured virtual hosts.
>
> * Note that the *SSLProxyEngine* directive should not, in general, be included in a virtual host that will be acting as a forward proxy (using  or ProxyRequests directives). *SSLProxyEngine* is not required to enable a forward proxy server to proxy SSL/TLS requests.

After enabling this directive things started to work as expected.